# Group dictionary values into objects in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, object, parsing

I have a Dictionary<string, string> object that has the following template of values:



**Key** = "data[0][name]"          | **Value** = "Test" 
**Key** = "data[0][type]"          | **Value** = "Type Test" 
**Key** = "data[0][description"    | **Value** = "Description Test" 
**Key** = "data[1][name]"          | **Value** = "Test" 
**Key** = "data[1][type]"          | **Value** = "Type Test" 
**Key** = "data[1][description"    | **Value** = "Description Test" 
**Key** = "data[2][name]"          | **Value** = "Test" 
**Key** = "data[2][type]"          | **Value** = "Type Test" 
**Key** = "data[2][description"    | **Value** = "Description Test" 


How can I parse this dictionary into their own objects with the values Name, Type, Description?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to declare your class type:

```
public class MyItem 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

If you were hoping to infer the type, that's technically possible using, say, a JSON or Tuple result, or maybe even generators or codegen/dynamic IL. But it's not really how .Net is made to work.

Then you can do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyItem> GetItems(Dictionary<string, string> items)
{
    // This assume every property is always populated
    int numItems = items.Count / 3; // 3 is the number of properties. 

    for(int i = 0;i<numItems;i++)
    {
        yield reutrn new MyItem() {
            Name = items[$"data[{i}][name]"],
            Type = items[$"data[{i}][type]"],
            Description = items[$"data[{i}][description]"]
        };
    }
}
```

If you can't infer how many items you might have based on the size of the dictionary alone, you're gonna have to parse out each item in the dictionary's `Keys` property to figure it out. The same it true if you're not sure in advance what your properties will be.

Comment: thank you, this worked. I was trying to do some much more complicated and this simplified my whole method

Answer (score 0):

Similar alternative:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//...
public struct DataItem
{
  public string name;
  public string type;
  public string description;
}
//...
public List<DataItem> CustomFn(Dictionary<string,string> dict) 
{
  var list = new List<DataItem>();
  int size = dict.Count/3;

  for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
  {        
    Func<string,string> t = (key) => {
      var dictkey = $"data[{i}][{key}]";          
      return dict.ContainsKey(dictkey) ? dict[dictkey] : null;
    };

    list.Add(new DataItem() {
      name = t("name"),
      type = t("type"),
      description = t("description"),
    });
  }   

  return list;   
}
```

update: check if key exists in dictionary